# Cómo cambiar la ruta en HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess

tengo un problema de ruta web en la cual una está mal ubicada y la quiero cambiar o redireccionar a la que quiero con el archivo .htaccess de mi página web. Intente crear una RewriteRule pero no funcionó. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

> Ruta erronea: https://mysite.com/swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/foto.(png.jpge,gif etc) - Ruta que quiero que direccione o cambie: https://mysite.com/photos/thumbnail/foto.(png.jpeg,gif etc)

Acá mi RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/?$ $1/photos/thumbnail$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Compruebe esta regla en la parte superior de su archivo .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^swf\/c_images\/navigator-thumbnail\/(.*)\.jpg$ /photos/thumbnail/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Reescribe la regla en tu enlace

```
mysite.com/swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/foto.jpg <> mysite.com/photos/thumbnail/foto
```

Y todas las jpg foto en /swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/ to /photos/thumbnail/

```
mysite.com/swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/any-foto.jpg <> mysite.com/photos/thumbnail/any-foto
```